# add together with product price * quantity already in assembly language of MASM with Irvine

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I try to add together the product price * quantity in the different products but the result is no correct.

**Customers choose the product number 1 -3:**

1. 10 quantity * 921 = RM 9210
2. 10 quantity * 289 = RM 2890
3. 10 quantity * 523 = RM 5230

==============================

Total: RM 17330

**Picture of output diagram:**

1. [Customers choose number 1 products and type 10 quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Ujv.png)
2. [Customers choose number 2 products and type 10 quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj3qe.png)
3. [Customers choose number 3 products and type 10 quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmWhw.png)

**Summary page**

[The quantity is correct but the total price is wrong, it should be RM 17330](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFiML.png)

**My code**

```
    .data
    msg16 db 0dh,0ah, "Quantity: ", 0
    Oxfordquantity dword 0
    Derbyquantity dword 0
    Blucherquantity dword 0
    ChelseaBootquantity dword 0
    Loaferquantity dword 0
    Broguesquantity dword 0
    
    msg17 db 0dh,0ah, "Added the products. Did you want to add again? (Y/N): ", 0
    answerYN2 db 0
    msg18 db 0dh,0ah, "Invalid Input. Must enter Y/N only.", 0
    ;=========== Men shoes price ===========
    Oxford dword 921
    Derby  dword 289
    Blucher dword 523
    ChelseaBoot dword 280
    Loafer dword 310
    Brogues dword 235
    ;=========== Men shoes price ===========

;==========================Summary page=============================
msg19 db 0dh,0ah, "########## This is Summary Page ##########", 0
msg20 db 0dh,0ah, "Dear ", 0
msg21 db ",", 0
msg22 db 0dh,0ah, "Your phone number: ", 0
msg23 db 0dh,0ah, "Your location: ", 0
msg24 db 0dh,0ah, "This is your order products summary:", 0dh,0ah, "************************************", 0
msg25 db 0dh,0ah, "Total Quantity of Oxford: ", 0
msg26 db 0dh,0ah, "Total Quantity of Derby: ", 0
msg27 db 0dh,0ah, "Total Quantity of Blucher: ", 0
msg28 db 0dh,0ah, "Total Quantity of ChelseaBoot: ", 0
msg29 db 0dh,0ah, "Total Quantity of Loafer: ", 0
msg30 db 0dh,0ah, "Total Quantity of Brogues: ", 0
msg31 db 0dh,0ah, "Sub Total: ", 0
msg32 db "RM ", 0
subTotal dword ?
;====================================================================

.code
;################################## Summary Page ##################################
Summary:
    ;##### Summary message #####
    lea edx, msg19
    call writeString
    call Crlf

    ;##### Display customer name #####
    lea edx, msg20
    call writeString
    lea edx, customerName
    call writeString
    lea edx, msg21
    call writeString
    call Crlf

    ;## Display phone number ##
    lea edx, msg22
    call writeString
    lea edx, customerContactNumber
    call writeString

    ;## Display location ##
    lea edx, msg23
    call writeString
    lea edx, customerLocation
    call writeString
    call Crlf

    lea edx, msg24
    call writeString
    
    ;## Display Total Quantity ##
    lea edx, msg25      ;Oxford quantity
    call writeString
    mov eax, Oxfordquantity 
    call WriteDec
    lea edx, msg26      ;Derby quantity
    call writeString
    mov eax, Derbyquantity 
    call WriteDec
    lea edx, msg27      ;Blucher quantity
    call writeString
    mov eax, Blucherquantity 
    call WriteDec
    lea edx, msg28      ;ChelseaBoot quantity
    call writeString
    mov eax, ChelseaBootquantity 
    call WriteDec
    lea edx, msg29      ;Loafer quantity
    call writeString
    mov eax, Loaferquantity 
    call WriteDec
    lea edx, msg30      ;Brogues quantity
    call writeString
    mov eax, Broguesquantity 
    call WriteDec

    ;## Display Sub Total ##
    lea edx, msg31
    call writeString
    lea edx, msg32
    call writeString
    mov eax, Oxfordquantity
    mov ebx, Oxford
    mul ebx
    mov subTotal, ebx
    ;call WriteDec
    ;call Crlf

    mov eax, Derbyquantity
    mov ebx, Derby  
    mul ebx
    mov subTotal, ebx
    ;call WriteDec
    ;call Crlf

    mov eax, Blucherquantity
    mov ebx, Blucher 
    mul ebx
    mov subTotal, ebx
    ;call WriteDec
    ;call Crlf

    mov eax, ChelseaBootquantity
    mov ebx, ChelseaBoot    
    mul ebx
    mov subTotal, ebx
    ;call WriteDec
    ;call Crlf

    mov eax, Loaferquantity
    mov ebx, Loafer 
    mul ebx
    mov subTotal, ebx
    ;call WriteDec
    ;call Crlf

    mov eax, Broguesquantity
    mov ebx, Brogues 
    mul ebx
    mov subTotal, ebx
    ;call WriteDec

    mov eax, subTotal
    add subTotal, 0
    call WriteDec
    ;################################## Summary Page ##################################
```

I very thank you if you can help me to solve these problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `mov subTotal, ebx` everywhere? 1) The product from `mul` will be in `eax` (actually `edx:eax`, but I'm guessing you only care about the lower 32 bits here). and 2) If you want to add all the subtotals together then you can only use `mov` for the first subtotal, while `add` should be used for the rest of them.

Comment: Also, if you don't need the high half of a 32x32 => 64-bit multiply, use `mov ecx, Broguesquantity` / `imul ecx, Brogues` to just do `ecx *= Brogues` or whatever without messing up any other registers.  You're writing 32-bit code so you can use other 386 features like the more convenient and efficient form of imul.

Comment: Also, single-step your code in a debugger to watch values in registers change (and examine memory since you're adding into memory instead of a register.)

Comment: wow, I need to thank you a  lot, you save my life! I changed the "mov subTotal, ebx" to "mov subTotal, eax". The result is correct already